# Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) implementation

Tags: c++, windows, prediction, lda

does someone know if there exists some implementation of LDA algorithm (no matter if library or application) for Win32 platform? Maybe in C/C++ or other language that can be compiled?

Answer (score 3):

Well, honestly I just googled LDA because I was curious of what it was, and the second hit was [a C implementation of LDA](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/lda-c/). It compiles fine with gcc, though some warnings show up. I don't know if it's pure ANSI C or not, but considering that there is gcc for windows available, this shouldn't be a problem. If you have trouble compiling, ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score 3):

[gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) has a very good Python implementation.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of examples:

[Gibbs LDA++ library](http://gibbslda.sourceforge.net/) on Sourceforge

[plda](http://code.google.com/p/plda/updates/list) for a parallel implementation

As Tamás has offered, please specify the issues that you are having finding a library so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The original implementation of LDA was written by David Blei and the source code (C) is still available at his website: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html as lda-c. The other implementations are for algorithms based upon LDA.

Answer (score -1):

We use [DCA](http://www.nicta.com.au/people/buntinew/discrete_component_analysis), written in C, scales well, has hyperparamenter optimization.

You could also consider [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/), written in Java, widely used.