# Non-GPL Open Source Latent Dirichlet Allocation Implementation/Library in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, machine-learning, nlp, lda

I know some implementations (mainly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230696/latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-implementation)) but they seemed to be all published unter GPL.

Are there any (platform independent) implementations without the GPL restrictions?

Comment: In other words, you want one under the MIT, BSD, or LGPL licence?

Comment: Or do you want a commercial license?

Comment: Or do you want a propitiatory licence? (@RedX GPL is a commercial and non-commercial license)

Comment: @Linuxios: there are more than that, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

Found this: [gensim](http://mloss.org/software/view/273/). A LGPL python library.

[mloss.org](http://mloss.org) is a great ressource for this kind of algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The second link in that question, [plda](http://code.google.com/p/plda/), is Apache 2 licensed not GPL.

Comment: Must have missed that... I'll check it out!